# angular 5 apps files are getting downloaded in less than 1 sec. but it takes 10 sec to render the initial page

Tags: angular, performance, nginx, angular5

Angular 5 application overall initial payload size is 1.7 MB which get downloaded in less than 2 sec, but after that it takes 8-10 sec to paint the home page.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pgenk.png)

Comment: And what is the question? Why? May be your pc is old. Maybe you did something wrong with routing. May be your app depends on external resources. Who knows?

Comment: Your app must have a serious problem then :)

Comment: Yes @enf0rcer, I have 16Gig Machine, very less external dependencies, I guess after downloading the build, it takes time to execute the initials calls, because whatever API i hit i get response in less than 500ms

Comment: Open chrome profiler, check what takes the most of time (parsing js, rendering ui, e.t.c)

Comment: Are you using a guard that takes too long?

Comment: Yes I am using AuthGaurds

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution to the above-mentioned problem.

Added a script in package.json

```
"build-prod": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --aot true --vendor-chunk true --common-chunk true --env=prod --delete-output-path=false",
```

after doing AOT while ng build and deploy on server, when you hit the example.com it first downloads the whole chunks and immediately starts executing it. whereas when you build withou --aot then after hitting example.com browser downloads the whole chunk takes time to compile and execute.

Also If you have you angular 2+ application in module wise that will help,  this is called lazy loading (lazy routed loading)

Hope this will help